# Should I use my credit or debit card when purchasing groceries?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, purchase

When I go grocery shopping, I almost always purchase enough to warrant using a card rather than cash.  I used to use my debit card for these transactions, but twice in the past (each incident about half a year apart) shortly after doing so I have had my credit union report that the account connected to my debit card had fraudulent charges, and I had to get the card replaced.

Since then I have been using my credit card for store purchases, because it is my understanding that credit cards come with built-in fraudulent charge insurance.  But I am wondering if this is actually more secure than using my debit card, and if there are any other concerns I should have with using my credit card for this regular (sometimes bi-weekly) purchase.  But on the other hand, my credit card does offer cash rewards, so using it frequently may be a better tradeoff.

It is better to use a credit or debit card when making my regular grocery purchases, or does it make no difference?

Comment: tell the grocery store...

Comment: @ssaltman I did.  They reacted with indifference.  I reacted by never going to that grocery store again.

Comment: Are either/both of the cards chip and PIN?

Comment: @Zibbobz when you "told the grocery store", did you talk to someone minimum wage, no benefits and no future in the company or did you talk to management?

Comment: @AdamJensen Local manager, who didn't seem to understand how it could be their fault.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For safety, I would always go with a credit card. The fraud protection is generally better, although that gap is closing and many debit cards include similar fraud protection now as well.

The key though is that in the event of a dispute, *your money* is at stake when you use a debit card (those funds might be unavailable for you to use), while on a credit card, it's the issuing bank's funds, and that's the bigger advantage I think.

Also many credit cards offer cash back/points on grocery store purchases so that's a possible advantage but not really relevant to the fraud/safety concern.

Comment: +1 I also like the rewards points, but my primary reason for making all purchases on a credit card (rather than debit) is to minimize the hassle of fraud.

Comment: My usual store only takes cash or debit (or EBT).  AFAIK, no one has managed to hack into $20 bills :-)

Comment: @jamesqf On the contrary: it's called "pickpocketing".

Comment: Or counterfeiting.

Comment: A store would have to have some pretty amazing advantage for me to continue shopping there these days if they don't take credit cards. It's my method of choice for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: A shop that doesn't accept credit/debit cards is just dumb. Transporting wads of cash to a bank securely costs **a lot more** (and the cost scales with the amount of cash) than all the costs of card processing combined (fees, hardware, ...). This is why they offer you cash back on card purchases too - to get rid of some of that expensive-to-deal-with cash.

Comment: American Express Blue Cash has a whopping 5% cash back on grocery store purchases once you've exceeded $6500 worth of purchases per year.

Comment: Credit cards also build credit history.  Another advantage, particularly when starting off as a young adult.

Comment: @neminem: No, pickpocketing would be the same as having your credit/debit card stolen.  But if I steal a $20 bill from you, you've lost only that $20.  I can't e.g. copy down the serial number off it, and use it to empty your bank account, or charge up to whatever your credit limit might be.  FTM, I don't even need to steal the physical card, just get the number and possibly a PIN.  And if you counterfeit a $20 bill and spend it somewhere, that doesn't really affect me.

Comment: @R..: You may think it's dumb, but the operators of my preferred grocery store chain (WinCo) think differently.  Since their prices are consistently cheaper, their selection better, and their stores more pleasant to shop in, than the local competition, I think they may have a point.  Nor do I see how the cost of transporting cash would scale with the quantity.  And I've never known a store that would offer cash back - indeed, gas stations hereabouts often charge less for cash than credit/debit.

Comment: @jamesqf That's because they don't have to cover the security cost of losing the transaction illegally made with a card - YOU do have to cover the cost if your cash is stolen.  And in *every* case where someone managed to get my card data, I got my money back.

Comment: @DanDascalescu AmEx blue Cash preferred is up to 6% now for fee card and 3% for a non annual fee. I am really struggling with a reason not to have this card unless you are single and eat out all the time.

Comment: @Vitalik, the main reason not to is the $6,500 spend required. Do the math sometime on how much you would have to spend *after* $6,500 to make the total cash back worth it, vs. using a card that just gives 1% or 1.5% cash back on everything. Not saying it won't work out better for you, but for me I was worse off. I still have one of those cards, just never really use it.

Comment: @briantist So why not just run 6% on 6K and then stop using it? It's $360 back on a card that costs $75/year. Sounds like a good deal. (in addition it gives 3% on gas without limit and 1% on everything else)

Comment: @Vitalik I just checked, it seems they changed the terms from when I last looked. Previously you didn't get 6% back on the first $6,000; you got a much lower cash back rate on the first $6,500 and didn't *start* getting 6% back until after that, for the year (then it reset). Sorry for the confusion.